# Does a complex sql statement is in a transcation on default?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Enviroment: 
  mysql(InnoDB)  
  autocommit=1 (open)
```

When I commit a sql like this:

insert with subquery

```
insert into t1(name, sex, num) 
select 'Jim' as name, 'male' as sex , count(1) as num from t1
where type= 'male'
```

Does the whole statement in a transaction? In other words, does it equals to 
below:

```
start transcation

select @num:=count(1) from t1 where sex = 'male'

insert into t1(name, sex, num) value ('Jim', 'male', @num)

commit
```

And not equal to

```
select @num:=count(1) from t1 where sex = 'male'

insert into t1(name, sex, num) value ('Jim', 'male', @num)
```

which without transcation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see if autocommit is **on** or **off**

```
select @@autocommit;
```

**Doku**

```
autocommit

Description: If set to 1, the default, all queries are committed immediately. The LOCK IN SHARE MODE and FOR UPDATE clauses therefore have no effect. If set to 0, they are only committed upon a COMMIT statement, or rolled back with a ROLLBACK statement. If autocommit is set to 0, and then changed to 1, all open transactions are immediately committed.
Commandline: --autocommit[=#]
Scope: Global, Session
Dynamic: Yes
Data Type: boolean
Default Value: 1
```

Comment: So does that mean that with autocommit=1,  that because a statement is commited on execution, that rollback isn't possible? Or would rollback still be possible if it's done in a transaction?

Comment: you can only rollback statements before commit. if autocommit is on the statement is directly committed.

Comment: Thanks you. I think I understand. if autocommit is open. every sql statement is one transcation, no matter it is a simple insert or having a subquery in it.